# Removing duplicates from output of COLLECT clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes of type Challenge, Entry, User, Comment

- An Entry can be PART_OF a Challenge
- A Challenge or Entry can be
  POSTED_BY a User
- A Comment can be POSTED_BY a User
- A Comment can be
  POSTED_IN a Challenge
- A User can LIKE a Challenge or an Entry

I'm trying to query all Entries that are PART_OF a Challenge that has been either LIKED or Commented by a specific user, or has an Entry posted by that same user (one or more of these conditions).

```
MATCH (u:User {id: 'r1tcX0vxW'})-[:LIKES]->(c:Challenge) 
WITH COLLECT (c) as likedChallenges
MATCH (c:Challenge)<-[:POSTED_IN]-(comment:Comment)-[:POSTED_BY]->(u) 
WITH likedChallenges, COLLECT (c) as commentedChallenges 
MATCH (c:Challenge)<-[:PART_OF]-(e:Entry)-[:POSTED_BY]->(u) 
WITH likedChallenges + commentedChallenges + COLLECT (c) AS allChallenges 
UNWIND allChallenges as c 
MATCH (e:Entry)-[:PART_OF]->(c) 
RETURN e;
```

I'm using COLLECT clauses to make this work, but the problem is there are duplicate output of Challenge nodes, and I'm not sure how to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` in the last clause to return distinct entries:

```
RETURN DISTINCT e;
```

Note: you have numerous syntax errors in your Cypher query. This should work better:

```
MATCH (u:User {id: 'r1tcX0vxW'})-[:LIKES]->(c:Challenge)
WITH u, COLLECT(c) as all
MATCH (c:Challenge)<-[:POSTED_IN]-(:Comment)-[:POSTED_BY]->(u) 
WITH u, all + COLLECT(c) AS all
MATCH (c:Challenge)<-[:PART_OF]-(:Entry)-[:POSTED_BY]->(u) 
WITH all + COLLECT(c) AS all
UNWIND all AS c
MATCH (e:Entry)-[:PART_OF]->(c)
RETURN DISTINCT e;
```

Answer (score 0):

@cybersam has the best answer for this scenario but for those who have collect in their return statement and can't use DISTINCT, I found apoc.coll.toSet to work too
https://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2019/01/12/neo4j-cypher-remove-consecutive-duplicates/

```
neo4j> WITH [1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,3] AS values
   RETURN [i in range(0, size(values)-1)
           WHERE i=0 OR values[i] <> values[i-1] | values[i] ] AS values;
+--------------------+
| values             |
+--------------------+
| [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3] |
+--------------------+
```

Comment: add the code snipet in addition to the link:neo4j> WITH [1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,3] AS values
       RETURN [i in range(0, size(values)-1)
               WHERE i=0 OR values[i] <> values[i-1] | values[i] ] AS values;
+--------------------+
| values             |
+--------------------+
| [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3] |
+--------------------+